# After loading a set of data (from a database) into Power BI using IDBC, where the loaded data are saved on my computer/server?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I used ODBC to connect to a database and loaded a big data (around 20 million rows) into Power BI desktop. Am I only connected to the database or I duplicated the data somewhere in my computer or on the server?

I would love to AVOID duplicating my data. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Import, the data was loaded into Power BI Analysis Server.
If you used Direct Query, it didn't load the data.

Comment: When you are using ODBC, the Power BI does not give you the "import" or "Direct Query" options!

Comment: Just tested, you're right. So it imports your data, but I wouldn't worry because it does a good job compressing it. Only try to avoid making a lot of transformations on top of your data source in Query Editor (like joins or merges or sorts)

Comment: If it is compressed, where it is saved? The size of my data is really big.

Comment: It saves it locally in SSAS I think.